# Event registration page formatting

Tags: civievent, online-registration, formatting

I'm previewing my event registration on TestDrive and I don't like the formatting at all. Is this something that I can modify in CiviCRM? Or is this a WordPress issue?
I want the text to go across the screen. It seems to be funneled down a column instead of across the screen.

***I WANT***
**Fri Only (13 & Up) (Includes automatic member discount of: 20% Member Discount) ***

***NOT:***
**Fri Only (13 &
Up) (Includes
automatic
member
discount of:
20% Member
[image]
Discount) ***

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by your WordPress theme.  If this site is only for CiviCRM, you can try changing your theme to something that looks nicer.

If not, you will need to make CSS edits in your theme.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. CiviCRM (via civicrm.css) is floating labels to the left with this code: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/ea8ae7ad83fb6ccf68a7f1f4cd0a56464bfb78e7/css/civicrm.css#L419
It is possible to override this behaviour in the theme of the CMS, but responsibility for the issue is squarely on CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0):

This is (probably) CiviCRM being a bit retro in how it thinks forms should display.

If your other forms are not doing this, then you'll probably notice that this behavior only happens with a wider screen, and if you shrink down your screen, it behaves in a more modern way with the labels above the form elements.

If you don't want this to happen, you can do some custom edits to your css, or you could also try out my CiviCRM theme here: https://github.com/adixon/toronto

This "theme" can be manually installed as a civicrm extension (not yet available as automated) and then 'enabled' for your front end within CiviCRM itself. All it really does is try to strip out some old-fasioned css that has been plaguing civicrm for a while (e.g. what you experienced, as well as some font-forcing).